# 3rd Party Media Controls For WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

Dear Guys
Could you help me to find out a good 3rd Party control for wpf i don't want to use media elements due to media player installation and many windows in Europe specially didn't install windows media player and users didn't like such a thing

I will install required codecs but for controls , any idea ?!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [WPF Media Kit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) and it works pretty well, it can use either DirectShow or Media Foundation as a renderer.